# Construct object by calling constructor (method) explicitly

Tags: c++, object, constructor

**Definition of class:**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace impress_errors {

#define BUFSIZE 512

class Error {
public:
    Error(int number);
    Error(std::string message);
    Error(const char *message);
    bool IsSystemError();
    std::string GetErrorDescription();

private:
    std::pair <int, std::string> error;
    char stringerror[BUFSIZE]; // Buffer for string describing error
    bool syserror;
};

}  // namespace impres_errors
```

I have some piece of code in file posix_lib.cpp:

```
int pos_close(int fd)
{
    int ret;
    if ((ret = close(fd)) < 0) {
        char err_msg[4096];
        int err_code = errno;
        throw impress_errors::Error::Error(err_code); //Call constructor explicitly
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And in another file fs_creation.cpp:

```
int FSCreation::GenerateFS() {
int result;
try {
    result = ImprDoMakeTree(); //This call pos_close inside.
}
catch (impress_errors::Error error) {
    logger.LogERROR(error.GetErrorDescription());
    return ID_FSCREATE_MAKE_TREE_ERROR;
}
catch (...) {
    logger.LogERROR("Unexpected error in IMPRESSIONS MODULE");
    return ID_FSCREATE_MAKE_TREE_ERROR;
}
if(result == EXIT_FAILURE) {
    return ID_FSCREATE_MAKE_TREE_ERROR;
}
return ID_SUCCESS;
}
```

**On my version of compiler this one is compiled and work correct:**
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5 (Ubuntu Maverick - 10.04)
**On another version of compiler:**
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2 (Ubuntu Narwhal - 11.04) it causes
error:
posix_lib.cpp: In function ‘int pos_close(int)’:
posix_lib.cpp:363:46: error: cannot call constructor ‘impress_errors::Error::Error’ directly
posix_lib.cpp:363:46: error: for a function-style cast, remove the redundant ‘::Error’
**Questions:**
1. *Why this work on one version of g++, and failed on another?*
2. *What happens when I explicitly call constructor for creating object? Is it correct?

And why this is working?*

Answer (score 5):

You are not calling the constructor (well, you are, but not in the way you mean it). The syntax `ClassName(constructor params)` means to create a temporary object of the type `ClassName`, using the given parameters for its constructor. So you aren't simply calling the constructor; you are creating an object.

So you are creating an `Error` object. Your problem is that the name of `Error` is `impress_errors::Error`, not "impress_errors::Error::Error". The second `::Error` would seem to be an attempt to name the constructor. Constructors don't have names; they are not functions that you can find and call at your whim (again, not in the way you mean it).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an error in the compiler which rejects it.  The code is
legal, but not for the reasons you think.  There is no such thing as
"calling constructor (method) explicitly", because constructors don't
have names (§12.1/1).  On the other hand, `impress_errors::Error::Error`
is the name of a type; class name injection (§9/2) means that the class
`impress_errors::Error` contains a declaration of the name `Error` in
the class, as a synonym for the name outside of the class.  So
`impress_errors::Error`, `impress_errors::Error::Error`,
`impress_errors::Error::Error::Error`, etc. all name the same type
(although only the first is idiomatic—the rest are all just extra
noise).  And when the name of a type is followed by a parenthesized
expression list, as is the case here, it is an "Explicity type
conversion (functional notation)". (§5.2.3—and the standard says it 
is an explicit type conversion even if the expression list is empty, or
contains more than one expression—don't ask me what "type" is
being converted in such cases.)  So `impress_errors::Error(err_code)` (or
`impress_errors::Error::Error(err_code)` means convert `err_code` into
an `impress_errors::Error`.  Which, in this case, will result in calling
the constructor, since that's the only way to convert an `int` into an
`impress_errors::Error`.  (It's possible, however, to construct cases
where the compiler will call a user defined conversion function on the
object being converted.)

Comment: @James Kanze: §3.4.3.1/2 appears to say otherwise. I do not have the final standard here, only n3290, but I'm positively sure the final document haven't changed much in this department. It seems to imply that `impress_errors::Error::Error` cannot be used as a type name, despite the injection.

Comment: @n.m I'm looking at n3291, but I don't see how it can apply here.
§3.4.3.1/2 starts by saying "In a lookup in which the constructor is an
acceptable lookup result[...]", which isn't the case here.

Comment: the example there says `A::A a; // error, A::A is not a type name`, why? Can it be a type name in another position? I know examples are not normative, but what's the intent here?

Comment: gcc seems to use the same interpretation as I do. When it sees an expression like `A::A(7)` the complaint is twofold: (1) `A::A` names a constructor and (2) constructors cannot be called directly. That is, it is an acceptable lookup result, but the usage constraint as per §3.4.3.1/2 is not met.

Comment: Also see 5.1.1/8: `Where class-name :: class-name is
used, and the two class-names refer to the same class, this notation names the constructor (12.1).` Compare this with the `A::~A` notation which names the destructor. This is despite that neither constructors nor destructors have names.

Comment: @n.m. The intent is difficult to judge from the text.  With regards to `A::A a;`, I suspect that it is because we are dealing with a declaration, and declaring a constructor in this manner would be legal.  But I can't be sure, since I wasn't there when the issue was discussed.  Following a `throw`, however, only an expression can occur, and there is no context in an expression where a constructor would be legal.  (It's entirely possible that the committee **intended** this statement to make using `A::A` as a type when just `A` would suffice, but the actual wording doesn't go that far.)

Comment: @n.m. §5.1.1/8 definitely seems clearer.  It also seems to contradict
§3.4.3.1; but since it is considerably clearer, perhaps we should take 
it at face value.  (In other words, I don't really see any way of making
it mean anything else, where as there is enough vagueness in §3.4.3.1 so
that it can be twisted a bit.  Anyway, §5.1.1/8 convinces me that I was
wrong in my original statement.)

Answer (score 0):

It should be ok if You do what compiler is asking You. Just remove one "Error" statement;> I'm not sure why this changed in gcc, but class_name::construction_name is just redundant. Compiler knows that You want to call constructor, because its name is the same as the name of the class

Answer (score 0):

While you could explicitly call the constructor using placement new, see [placement operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax), you don't have an object or piece of memory in which to place the object yet.  Probably easier to use something like

throw new MyError(MyParams);

and make the exception handler responsible for deleting it.  FWIW Microsoft use this approach with MFC.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to `new` an exception object and expect the handler to delete it; better to throw the object directly and avoid the possibility of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same error message.

The solution is to change this line:

```
throw impress_errors::Error::Error(err_code); //Call constructor explicitly
```

to

```
throw impress_errors::Error(err_code); //Call constructor explicitly
```

In C++ you can call the base class constructor inside a derived class constructor, just never use the scope resolution operator ::